# Total Dissolved Solids and Alkalinity

Tags: water, ph, concentration, ions

I need to calculate total dissolved solids (TDS) of various groundwater samples from chemical analyzes. I have concentrations of ions/molecules in mg/L. I’ve found various formulas to calculate TDS but the ions/molecules I have never match.  I don’t have a lot knowledge in chemistry.

**Here are the three equations I have found. (As i said, I found many different equations and I don't know which one I should use):**

**Eq. 1** : TDS=Na(+) +K(+) +Ca(2+) +Mg(2+) + Fe^(2+) +HCO3(-) +Cl(-) +SO4(2-) +NO3(-)

**Eq.2** : TDS=0.6*Alkalinity (as CaCO3) +Na(+) +K(+) +Ca(2+) +Mg(2+) +Fe(2+) +Cl(-) +SO4(2-) +NO3(-) **[1]**

**Eq.3** : TDS=cations +anions +SiO2

**Problems/questions I have:**

•I don’t have the concentration of HCO3(-).

•I have the concentration of CaCO3. In natural waters, alkalinity (mg/L CaCO3) is HCO3(-)+CO3(2-) +OH(-) +H(+). At pH under 8.3, could I simply convert the concentration of CaCO3 in HCO3(-)? If yes and if the pH is over 8.3, is there a way to calculate the concentration of both HCO3- and CO3(2-)?

•I don’t have the concentration for NO3-. I only have the concentration for NO3-+NO2. Is there a way to isolate the concentration of NO3(-)?

•I don’t have the concentration for SiO2. I only have the concentration for Si. Could I simply use the concentration of SiO2?

•The pH of my water samples varies from 6 to 9.

•Also, I don't have the samples so I cannot titrate the water or measure electrical conductivity.

Thank you!

References:

**[1]** Federation, W. E., & American Public Health Association. (2005). Standard methods for the examination of water and wastewater. American Public Health Association (APHA): Washington, DC, USA.

Comment: I am sorry this is not the way it works. Do you remember the mathematical requirement that if we have 9 unknowns we need 9 independent linear equations. Nobody solves such equations for TDS. Here is the step-by-step process https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Total-Dissolved-Solids

Comment: Sorry, english is not my first language. I meant that I don't know which equation is better. Also, I don't have the water samples, so I cannot use electrical conductivity or titrate the water samples.

Comment: No problem with English and no need to say sorry for that. Without conductivity you $cannot$ measure TDS easily. None of the equations are useful or officially accepted ones. Could you clarify what is the context of your problem? Also clarify what information do you have.

Comment: Can you get hold of this book "Environmental Laboratory Exercises for Instrumental Analysis Frank M. Dunnivant". It will explain everything to you.

Comment: I would like to calculate TDS of groundwater samples to compare it to values of TDS measured in wetlands. Then, I would like to establish if there is a connection between groundwater and wetlands. 

I foud the second equation in the _Standard methods for the examination of water and wastewater_ so I think it is possible to calculate TDS from cations and anions. And thanks, I'll try to get the book!

Comment: In order to implement equation 2, you need titration data. I haven't seen this equation but it must have a charge balance.  By charge balance I mean the positive charges must equal the negative charges in number. Your reference is highly reliable. Please get hold of the book I suggested as well. It talks about mass and charge balance. Whoever gave you the data ask them if CaCO3 came from titration or not?

Comment: yes CaCO3 comes from titration! So I can use it to calculate the HCO3(-) concentration and CO3(2-) concentration. And yes, all the samples I have are balanced.

Comment: I think you can try the second equation and make sure you double check with experts before publishing it.